# Get total parent-cases with at least one sub-case with a particular value

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to get a count of parent-cases that have *at least* one subcase with a particular value.

- Parent case_type is "foo" and sub case case_type is "bar".
- Each case_type "bar" has a variable "degrees"
- I need the count of all "foo" with *at least* one "bar" where degrees < 100
- I **do not** want to double-count a "foo" if it has multiple "bar" that meet the degrees requirement.
- I expect a high count (2,000+) of case_type foo per device
- There could be from 0 to 10+ case_type bar per foo
- I'm currently attempting this in a form that edits cases case_type bar

I've attempted to do this with a casedb bar "count" inside a foo "count" but I couldn't figure out how to phrase the interior casedb parent @case_ID reference.

I wonder if this could be done with a nested repeat group, but I'm confused by the fact that the number of "bar" per "foo" is dynamic.

Before I invest significant more time in this I'm wondering if anyone has done something similar and what your solution looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a repeat group with model iteration over the `foo` casetype.  The model iteration ID query would be:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_type = "foo"][@status = 'open']/@case_id
```

This will create one repeat per `foo` case.

Inside the repeat group, you'd have a count of the number of `bar` cases are under the current `foo` case:

```
if(count(instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_type = "bar"][@status = 'open']
   [index/parent = current()/../@id][degrees < 100]) > 0, 1, 0)
```

This returns 1 if there are any `bar` cases under that `foo` case with degrees < 100.

Then outside of the repeat group, you can sum the above calculation over all the `foo` cases to get your total:

```
sum(/data/repeat_group/has_bar_case)
```

I don't know about the performance of this solution with the case load you have.  You probably have to load test it.

Comment: worked with one change, needed add "item" in the sum path so: sum(/data/repeat_group/**item**/has_bar_case)

Comment: also, had to put the repeat group in a place where I'd actually swipe past it and then follow it with the "sum" function, then I could use the returned data.